# How can I access ion-input number value under my ngAfterViewInit() in Ionic2?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2

I have taken an ion input value of number type and I want to access the value under my ngAfterViewInit, I am getting undefined value, Please do let me know the proper solution?

Here is the code below:

```
<ion-input id="qty" type="number" placeholder="Enter Stop Index" (ngModel)="stop"></ion-input>
```

code:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {

         var slidetostop= (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('qty')).value;


}
```

Comment: can you add the full component side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do achieve it with javascript. Have a look of below code.

```
    var slidetostop ="8" //you can put any static number.
    document.getElementById("qty").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
        slidetostop  =  parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("qty")).value);
       }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks , Its help me a lot. saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [(ngModel)] syntax here:

```
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Enter Stop Index" [(ngModel)]="qty"></ion-input>
```

and reference it in your controller

```
export class SimpleNgModelController implements AfterViewInit {
    qty: number = 0;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log("afterviewinit: ", this.qty); //console logs 0
    } 

    setValue() {
        this.qty = 100; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the input value within my ngAfterViewInit() at runtime, by this I cannot able to use local variable to my ngAfterViewInit. when we access this.qty value within my ngAfterViewInit, got error undefined property qty? @csim

Comment: do you set qty to some default value? because if you don't and you fetch the value right after the component's views and child views are initialized the value is undefined.

Comment: Yes I am setting default value 0 and getting "Cannot read property 'qty' of undefined" while accessing the property value under my ngAfterViewInit(). @csim.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'qty' of undefined" sounds like another issue - could you provide the full code pls?